# Error compiling HMMER v3.2.1

Tags: software-installation, hmmer

I tried to compile HMMER v3.2.1 in Cygwin using

```
./configure
```

followed by

```
make
```

or

```
make install
```

but failed. I got this [config.log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aMXNQOiftf09XHW8B0pXVbt-Fdk1CWtD/view) to troubleshoot and I suspect the solution is in this line:

```
configure:2908: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

What does it mean? Is it really all I need to address? I followed the installation steps [in this document](http://eddylab.org/software/hmmer/Userguide.pdf).

Comment: It means you need to download a C compiler. I would recommend using gcc!

Comment: Have a look here on how to install gcc https://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8

Comment: gcc is a C compiler

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend to use [Bioconda](https://bioconda.github.io/index.html) instead of compiling. It is one of the channels ("distributors of packages") in [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/) which is basically a package source for [conda](https://conda.io/docs/).

In short - conda allows you to create virtual environments isolated from system and to install various precompiled software packages with one command (so, by the way, you can easily use multiple software versions on one system). Also, Bioconda is just one channel aiming on various bioinformatics software, but many more packages can be found in aforementioned Anaconda Cloud.

Tutorial how to start using Bioconda is on its homepage, and it is really easy (far more easier than to struggle with compiling).

[Bioconda HMMER package](https://bioconda.github.io/recipes/hmmer/README.html)

P.S. Of course there are cases in which you need a specific build of given software. Than it is really needed to compile manually.

Comment: Thank you. The website says "Bioconda supports only 64-bit Linux and Mac OSX." I am a Windows user, so I assume I will need to go back to compiling. Bioconda sounds amazing though; thanks for bringing it to my/our attention.

Comment: I tried to set up channels with `conda config --add channels defaults`, `conda config --add channels bioconda` & `conda config --add channels conda-forge` in my Anaconda prompt which seemingly worked, but `conda install hmmer` didn't.

Comment: @JernejT On Windows? And what does `conda install hmmer` output? Anyway, Linux is much more supported platform for bioinformatics. Worth to try :)